# hierarchical data model in mysql

Tags: mysql

how to write tree structure query for following  table. the table is dynamically add , delete  ,edit so that query should be dynamically. In Oracle very easy retrieve the query.

how to retrieve the result using mysql database.

---

node_id   :     parent_id   :    name  :       type

---

1         :       0         :    root    :     dir

2         :        1         :    P1       :    dir

3         :        2      :       C1    :       file

4         :        2       :      C2      :     file

5         :        1         :    P2       :    dir

6          :       5        :     C1      :     file

7         :        5        :     C2      :     file

8          :       5        :     P2_1     :    dir

9         :        8        :    P2_1_C1   :   file

Comment: MySQL doesn't support recursive queries. You'll need to do a looped series of queries or build your structure client-side.

Answer (score 0):

There is something like a left-right strategy for making it look like a tree in the table.  This will require some additional updates when adding/deleting data.  It is well explained here - http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/